# Cellular data subscription costs

Tags: data-request, internet, telecom

The US Census [July 2013 Computer and Internet Use Supplement](http://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/cps/techdocs/cpsjul13.pdf) surveys US households and asks "How much does your Internet service provider charge you per month?" From this, I can get an empirical distribution of US households' monthly Internet service costs.

This data is mainly about fixed broadband (i.e. home Internet access), however. I am looking for a data set that will allow me to compute this same distribution for cellular data plans.

There are various reports that compile the cost of selected mobile broadband plans (e.g. the [FCC International Broadband Data Report](https://www.fcc.gov/document/fifth-international-broadband-data-report) appendix), but not the number of subscribers for each plan. So these don't really help me.

Is there a data set that allows me to compute the distribution of monthly cost of cellular data subscription in a population? I prefer US, but would also be happy with data for another population.